# Form/code is not transfering to excel wb/ws, and when/if it does, its slow

Tags: excel, vba, transfer

I've put together a code to transfer form data to a spreadsheet. It was working fine but the other night I started making changes to it without realizing that was my core code and didn't have a back up. (it was late) I don't recall what I changed. Now it wont transfer the form data 100% of the time and when it does, its slow. I mean... like 35 seconds to update slow. Can anyone offer any hints or help on how this could be improved and/or fixed? Any help would be appreciated.

```
 Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If ComboBox2.Value = "" Or ComboBox3.Value = "" Or ComboBox6.Value = ""      Or ComboBox7.Value = "" Or ComboBox8.Value = "" Or ComboBox9.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox ("The form is not complete")
    Exit Sub
Else
End If

 Workbooks("Language Line April AM - 2019.xlsm").Worksheets("2019 LL DB").Activate

 Dim lastrow As Long, count As Long

 lastrow = Sheet7.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 lastrow = lastrow + 1

 Cells(lastrow, 1) = ComboBox6.Value 'Tester
 Cells(lastrow, 2) = TextBox4.Value 'Date
 Cells(lastrow, 3) = TextBox5.Value 'Meridiem
 Cells(lastrow, 4) = TextBox6.Value 'LOB
 Cells(lastrow, 5) = TextBox7.Value 'Language
 Cells(lastrow, 6) = ComboBox4.Value 'Phone Options
 Cells(lastrow, 7) = ComboBox6.Value 'Representative
 Cells(lastrow, 8) = TextBox4.Value 'Supervisor
 Cells(lastrow, 9) = TextBox5.Value 'Manager
 Cells(lastrow, 10) = TextBox6.Value 'Director
 Cells(lastrow, 11) = TextBox7.Value 'Location
 Cells(lastrow, 12) = ComboBox7.Value 'Whisper
 Cells(lastrow, 13) = ComboBox8.Value 'UAD Indicator
 Cells(lastrow, 14) = TextBox8.Value 'Results for system
 Cells(lastrow, 15) = ComboBox9.Value 'Free Translator Offer
 Cells(lastrow, 16) = TextBox9.Value 'Results for Rep offer
 Cells(lastrow, 17) = TextBox12.Value 'Comments

 ActiveWorkbook.Save

 MsgBox "Entry has been logged!"

    ComboBox2.Value = ""
    ComboBox3.Clear
    ComboBox4.Clear
    ComboBox4.Value = ""
    ComboBox5.Clear
    ComboBox6.Value = ""
    ComboBox7.Value = ""
    ComboBox8.Value = ""
    ComboBox9.Clear

    TextBox12.Value = ""

    CheckBox1.Value = False

    TextBox4.Value = ""
    TextBox5.Value = ""
    TextBox6.Value = ""
    TextBox7.Value = ""
    TextBox8.Value = ""
    TextBox9.Value = ""
    TextBox13.Value = ""
```

End Sub

Comment: Is something supposed to happen after the `Else`?

Comment: No. It would not allow me to compile without it. Also, there is an "End Sub" in the code I just forgot to put it on here.

Answer (score 1):

Using `exit` is not a good practice. You could use something like that instead:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If ComboBox2.Value = "" Or ComboBox3.Value = "" Or ComboBox6.Value = ""      Or ComboBox7.Value = "" Or ComboBox8.Value = "" Or ComboBox9.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox ("The form is not complete")
Else
'your code here

End If
end Sub
```

Using the `.Activate` method and leaving excel to figure out which `cells` or `worksheets` or workbooks are being referenced is not a good practice either.

Try this instead:

```
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim book as Workbook
Set book=Workbooks("Language Line April AM - 2019.xlsm")
Set sht1 = book.Worksheets("2019 LL DB")
```

Then you can reference the cells like so:

```
sht1.cells(lastrow,1).value=""
```

The same applies to `sheet7`. Is it the same as `2019 LL DB`? Then it should be referenced accordingly.

Not referencing the user form to which your controls belong, is not a good practice either. Try this instead:

```
userform.ComboBox2.Value="" 'where userform is your userform's name
```

Alternatively, if you want to avoid repeating `userform.xxx`, you can try this:

```
With userform 'your userform's name
    .combobox1.Value = ""
    .textbox1.Value = ""
End With
```

Finally, try using meaningful names for your variables and objects. For example `combobox6` could be renamed to `testerComboBox` or whatever is meaningful to you.

Using good practices will help you keep better track of your code and you'll find it easier to troubleshoot and debug it.

Comment: Thank you! You supported something I was working on before I asked the question. I was just missing a couple of things you indicated in your answer! Thank you for kick-starting this old brain! Much appreciated!

Comment: Glad I could be of help! :)